# Autocomplete Form - Assigning display text to a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I've taken over on a project for a firm and have been working on some features of their website that need improvement. One of these features is their search functions. However, I've hit a snag that I can't seem to get around.

The way their database works is they assign a specific value to a location, meaning to conduct a search for that location, it needs to have that specific value for the search to work. For example.

```
Bradford = GB.ENEI.0500
```

Now this wouldn't be a problem if we used a drop down in the form and used:

```
<option value="GB.ENEI.0500">Bradford</option>
```

As part of a select form, but this is unpractical as the list of locations is in the 1000(s). The user obviously can't just type in `Bradford` as the database is not assigning the value, so it would return nothing in the search.

To combat this annoying design I decided to use an autocomplete form, so for example, if the user begun to type Bradford, it would then suggest this as a search term to the user, the user then selects it and it assigns the value (`GB.ENEI.0500`) to Bradford.

But this is where my problem arises. I can set the value to `GB.ENEI.0500` but then it displays as that to the user, which to them means nothing and as far as they're concerned, is NOT Bradford. If I set the value to `Bradford`, it will display as Bradford to the user, but then it is not taking the correct value and the search fails.

Below is my form HTML:

```
<form action="https://example.net/example/Search/Results" method="GET" class="mpatsform" id="SearchForm" name="SearchForm">

    <input type="text" name="Keywords" id="Keywords" class="ico-01" placeholder="e.g. administrator" value=""/>     
    <input type="text" name="Location" id="autocomplete" class="ico-02" placeholder="e.g. bradford" value=""/>

    <button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

HTML Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/location-autocomplete.js"></script>
```

JavaScript (`location-autocomplete.js`): ***Note I've shortened this as there is a huge number of locations, but the layout is all the same.***

```
$(function(){
  var locations = [
    { value: '', data: 'All Locations' },
    { value: 'GB.ENEI.0500', data: 'Bradford' },
    ...
    { value: 'GB.ESEL.0000', data: 'Middlesex' },

  ];
});
```

The actual autocomplete works, it suggest the values. But I need it to display Bradford (not `GB.ENEI.0500`) but when the search is run, it runs that value and not Bradford.

Is there a way to do this? I'm thinking that my layout of the JavaScript is where I'm going wrong?

I've tried to explain this as best I could, but if you need any further information please let me know and I will do my best to do so.

Comment: Could you make use of `data-` attributes to hold the important value and the `value` attribute to hold the display value. Then when a user selects an option you extract the `data-` attribute and process however you need to. Thoughts?

Custom data attibutes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: I see you're using jquery autocomplete which provides a on `select` function you can set. This would be the time to extract out the important value from a custom `data-` attribute.

Comment: Hi @LukeStoward I did try switching the data and value information around. It shows `Bradford` but then it passes through the wrong value, therefore breaking the search.

Comment: I will look into the on `select` function. Thanks @LukeStoward

Comment: i'm not referring to the `data` attribute but instead custom HTML5 `data-` attributes. Note the difference. You can add custom attributes to elements that can hold a particular value and aren't manipulated by the browser at all. Example: `data-version="0.0.1"`

Comment: I think you should put the selected value in a hidden field and based on that selected value pick a value from a map and use that to display. But on form submission send only the hidden field.

Comment: @LukeStoward Thanks for your help on this, pin-pointing `onSelect` helped to to fix this issue and I appreciate your help! Solution posted below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a fix to this problem! I'd like to point out and thank @LukeStoward for reminding me that JQuery autocomplete provides a `onSelect` function and that is how I fixed this problem.

To start I created a third hidden `<input>` surrounded by a new div:

```
<div id="outputbox">
    <input type="hidden" name="Location" id="outputcontent" />
</div>
```

Then inside the same JavaScript file (`location-autocomplete.js`) I wrote the following:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  lookup: locations,
  onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    var theData = $('#outputcontent');
    theData.val(theData.val() + suggestion.data);
  }
});
```

So what this is doing is looking up the data from my locations list and on the selection of a value (`Bradford` for example) it would then set the variable `theData` to the data associated to Bradford (`GB.ENEI.0500`) and set the value for ID `outputcontent`.

This therefore allows me to run a search for a location, and show the actual name of the location, but the query sent to the database will read it as the data associated to it (`GB.ENEI.0500` NOT `Bradford`).

I hope this helps anybody who has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be done like this.

When the form submission is triggered. Pick the value from the data map and replace it before submission. So keep everything as it is but just before the submit replace the field value to the correct one.

Something like this.

```
$("#SearchForm").on("submit", function(){
  $("input[name='Location']").val(REPLACE_WITH_THE_REQUIRED_VALUE);
  return true;
});
```